# How to save .DOC file with expo-file-system in react-native?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm having trouble saving a `.DOC` file using `expo-file-system`.

I'm getting the following feedback:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Invalid argument "localUri". It
> must be a string!]

This is my current code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const saveFile = async () => {
      const { granted } = await Notifications
        .requestPermissionsAsync()
        .then((response) => response)
        .catch((error) => error);

      console.log(granted);

      if (granted) {
        data.map(async (index) => {
          const date = new Date(index.synchronization)

          const formattedDate = date.toISOString().split('T')[0];

          const fileUri = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}${formattedDate}.doc`;

          console.log(fileUri)

          await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(
            fileUri,
            "Hello World, i'am saving this file :)",
            {
              encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.UTF8
            });

          const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(`${fileUri}`);
          await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(asset);
          console.log(asset);

        });
      }
    }
    saveFile();
  }, [data]);
```

The error is probably occurring on this line:

```
const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(`${fileUri}`);
await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(asset);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I did!

It's a boring prank these promises

```
const { uri } = await MediaLibrary
            .createAssetAsync(`${fileUri}`)
            .then((response) => response)
            .catch((error) => error);;
await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(uri);
```

Necessita do uso de `then` and `catch`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).